# fms port error after installed

Tags: flash, flash-media-server, fms3

I installed fms 3.5 and actually am running apache for php in 8080 and want to make this fms service in different port and made it as 8083 while installing,

After installed when am starting fms using

./fmsmgr server fms start

it shows error message and i checked in messages file it gives already that port is used by someone

"Mar 26 03:59:51 u15393552 Adaptor[12576]: Failed to initialize listeners for adaptor admin, FMS is already running or other adaptor admin"

please find me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Adobe Flash Media Server uses port 1935 for the RTMP (Real-Time Messaging Protocol). This port was assigned to Adobe for the Flash Media Server by the IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority).

If a firewall is being used, this port needs to be opened. Otherwise, the server needs to be configured to use a different port in the tag of Adaptor.xml. Below is what the default entry for the  tag looks like:

```
<HostPortList>
<!-- Specifies what IP address and port(s) to bind to. This is specified -->
<!-- as a string in the form"<ip>:<port>,<port>,...,<port>". -->
<!-- For example, "127.0.0.1:1935,80,443". This says to bind to the IP -->
<!-- address of 127.0.0.1 on ports 1935, 80, and 443. You can bind to -->
<!-- any IP by not specifying anything in front of the colon. -->
<!-- For example, ":1935,80,443". This says to bind to any IP on ports -->
<!-- 1935, 80, and 443. If no colon is found, the data is assumed to be -->
<!-- an IP address, and will bind to port 1935 as the default. -->
<!-- For example, "127.0.0.1". This says to bind to IP 127.0.0.1 on port -->
<!-- 1935. If a colon is found but no ports are specified after it, port -->
<!-- 1935 is used as the default port in which to bind. -->
<!-- For example, "127.0.0.1:". This says to bind to IP 127.0.0.1 on -->
<!-- port 1935. If you wish to bind to multiple IP addresses on this -->
<!-- adaptor, specify additional <HostPort> tags; 1 for each additional -->
<!-- IP that you wish to bind to. NOTE: Another adaptor may also try to -->
<!-- bind to the same IP-port combination resulting in a conflict. This -->
<!-- is considered a conflict since it is undesirable to have more than -->
<!-- one adaptor listening on the same IP-port pair. To resolve this -->
<!-- conflict, the first adaptor to do the bind - wins. A warning will -->
<!-- be logged indicating that the specified IP-port combo is in-use. -->
<HostPort>:1935</HostPort>
</HostPortList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the [Configure ports](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/configadmin/WSdb9a8c2ed4c02d261d76cb3412a40a490be-8000.html) section of the FMS docs. It contains info about configuring ports for RTMP, HTTP, and RTMFP. It also has links to port testers.